# Can I tell my browser to render a page as if I were in another locale?

Tags: javascript, datetime, datepicker, locale, fullcalendar

I am in the US and have Irish client.  I need to ensure that all of the date/times are rendering properly in the European fashion.

I am using JQuery's datepicker and full calendar.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can change the locale on your computer using the Control Panel if you have Windows.  Also, refer to http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-accept-lang-locales and you will see that a lot of applications use this header among possible other headers to determine a locale.